# "to" in "Inference to the best explanation"

Tags: prepositions

The verb infer is used with direct object or with that clause ([+](https://www.lexico.com/definition/infer)). What is, then, the meaning of the preposition "to" in "inference to the best explanation" (or abduction, [+](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/))?

Comment: Your quote needs more context.

Comment: @GEdgar (1) Critics have accused this argument of being circular. Specifically, it has been said that the argument rests on a premise—that scientific methodology is informed by approximately true background theories—which in turn rests on an inference to the best explanation for its plausibility; (2) Specifically, it has been said that the argument rests on a premise ... which in turn rests on an inference to the best explanation for its plausibility (From [the second reference in the original post](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/))

Comment: @Jim, can you give another example with an implicit "leading"?

Comment: “Take the path [leading] to the barn.”

Comment: There is nothing unusual about a noun needing a preposition even though it is formed from a verb that doesn't.

Comment: @jsw29 True in general, beside the point in this case, as inference too seems not to be used with "to" (see examples in COCA collocation search, for example).

Comment: When performing an inference one moves **from** its premises **to** its conclusion, so *to* is a natural choice to fill the blank in *inference __ the conclusion*. How else would one connect *inference* with *the conclusion* or any specification of the conclusion? (In this case the conclusion is the best explanation, but the choice of the preposition does not depend on what the conclusion is.)

Comment: @jsw29, now, "to" seems to me more natural. However, if I were to chose, I would opt for "of" (or using that-clause): Her inference of his guilt was seriously flawed.